# Parse ответа из Oauth VKApi

Tags: android, vkontakte-api, oauth, android-vksdk

Всем привет, работаю с вк апи. Случился затык с выводом имени авторизованного пользователя в моем приложении. Не могу спарсить полученный response. Подскажите кто сталкивался. Вот кусок кода

```
 public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {

            super.onComplete(response);
            JSONArray resp = new JSONArray();

            try {
                resp = response.json.getJSONArray("response");
            } catch (JSONException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            JSONObject user = new JSONObject();

            try {
                user = resp.getJSONObject(0);
            } catch (JSONException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            userName.setText(user.toString());

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

заработался видимо )`VKApi.users().get().executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
                        VKApiUser user = ((VKList<VKApiUser>)response.parsedModel).get(0);
                        userName.setText(user.first_name + " " + user.last_name);
                    }
                });`